# Trying to use xTerm to send command or control key combinations

Tags: terminal, xtermjs

when using xTermJS, I am trying to use a UI to send commands, rather than just typing.. It's the project..

So, I sometimes need to send key combinations. Running on a Mac, I need to send "control+X" aka ^X

However, it doesn't seem like this is possible? At least not that anyone has published. IS it possible? I can use ASCII and hex characters to send, return, shift, arrow keys, etc. Can I do this "control" and/or "control+X" combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just as I was posting this querstion, I found the answer.
I found it here: https://mw.lojban.org/papri/List_of_ASCII_letterals#ASCII_control_code_chart

under `ASCII control code chart`, under `^X` which has the ASCII code of `18`, which I send to xTermJs as `\x18`. This immediately solved my problem.

Seems like even these character combinations are defined as 1 ASCII character, and not 2 used together. In this case, my Control+X character is actually called a `"Cancel"` character.

Comment: Welcome to the world of ASCII control chars ;) Please note that there is one more indirection in this game for many fundamental keystrokes - termios[CC] settings. While I have not seen any normal process messing around with those (beside some shells disabling a few), still things like process control is defined via those (e.g. SIGINT, normally mapped to Ctrl-C or 0x03). In theory a process could change that to any ASCII char - so to be on the safe side, it would be good to eval termios[CC] as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ascii representations of decimal 0 through 31 are all escape codes representing combinations of the Ctrl key plus another character.  The ascii characters used are taken from 4 rows below (add 64) on the ascii chart (decimal 64 through 94).   For example
decimal 64 is ascii @ => decimal 00 is ascii Ctrl + @
decimal 65 is ascii A => decimal 01 is ascii Ctrl + A
decimal 66 is ascii B => decimal 02 is ascii Ctrl + B

(some ASCII tables represent the Ctrl key with the carat '^' symbol as in ^@ instead of Ctrl + @)

The chart image below shows the binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal and escape codes/ascii representation for the first 128 values.  As an online reference I recommend [this ASCII Table](https://ss64.com/ascii.html) (from the excellent reference website [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/)).  Or you can modify [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nnM931DYfH7SrW1oPzToMQvAvjtF5h6j/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112628650716960297970&rtpof=true&sd=true) and make your own ascii chart.  [This version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MCpoUqIwQ1qOpFI88m6huYk2zbhQV_Ab/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112628650716960297970&rtpof=true&sd=true) has the original control code names once used by teletype machines.
[image]